# combobox.column property returns invalid use of null in vba

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, combobox, null

I am a database//Access noob, so bear with me. I have a database set up to keep track of Consultants and their Vendors for a tech consulting company. Some consultants are their own vendors, and some have third-party vendors that handle their contracting. In the case where a consultant is also their own vendor, the contact information is the same for both. Contact Info is stored in a separate table, with primary key ContactID and foreign key fields for ConsultantID (primary key in ConsultantT) and VendorID (primary key in VendorT).

In the case that the relevant Contact Info has already been entered on one of the forms, I want to be able to select the already existing Contact Info record and tell the database to add the other foreign key ID field to the existing record based on the record on the main form. So, for example, if I have already entered Contact Info for Consultant A via the Consultant form, when I open the Vendor form to add Consultant A's vendor I want the option to select "Consultant A" from a combo box and have their info populate VendorsF's Contact Info form while adding the VendorID to the already existing Contact Info record for Consultant A.

I think I've almost worked it out, but am stuck on one last thing. Right now I have a popup form (ChooseConsultantInfoF) for selecting an existing ContactInfo record. On that form I have a search combobox (SelectConsultantCombo) to select the existing record, and a command button (SaveConsultantbtn) which I've tried to code to Update the ContactInfoT and add the VendorID from the current record on the VendorsF to the existing record in ContactInfoT. Here is the all of the code for the popup form:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub SaveConsultantbtn_Click()
Dim stupid As Long
stupid = SelectConsultantCombo.Column(0)
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE ContactInfoT SET VendorID = (Forms!VendorsF!VendorID) Where ContactInfoID = " & stupid & ";"
End Sub

Private Sub SelectConsultantCombo_AfterUpdate()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
rst.FindFirst "ContactInfoID = " & Me!SelectConsultantCombo
Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
leave:
Me!SelectConsultantCombo = Null
If Not rst Is Nothing Then Set rst = Nothing
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

When I try to put it into action, I get Error 94: Invalid use of Null and it pulls up

```
stupid = SelectConsultantCombo.Column(0)
```

I know the code block works apart from that--I tried the Click event once with a numeric value instead of the variable:

```
 Private Sub SaveConsultantbtn_Click()
    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE ContactInfoT SET VendorID = (Forms!VendorsF!VendorID) Where ContactInfoID = 1 ;"
    End Sub
```

without any trouble, so the issue must be in calling the combobox's column.

I also tried defining the variable with Nz to allow Null:

```
stupid = Nz(Me.SelectConsultantCombo.Column(0), 0)
```

and that gets the code working also, but still doesn't save my VendorID to the record in ContactInfoT.  None of the columns in the combobox contain Null values (none that I can find, anyway). Dunno if this is useful, but the Row Source of the combobox is:

```
SELECT ContactInfoT.ContactInfoID, ConsultantT.ConsultantID, ConsultantT.FirstName, ConsultantT.LastName FROM ConsultantT INNER JOIN ContactInfoT ON ConsultantT.ConsultantID = ContactInfoT.ConsultantID ORDER BY ConsultantT.[LastName], ConsultantT.[FirstName];
```

Does anyone know why Access doesn't recognize my combobox.column property? Or is there another way to write this up in VBA to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

First try `stupid = Me.SelectConsultantCombo.Column(0)` (you are missing the `Me.` part).

But what you should really do is make sure your bound column on the combo box is set correctly and just use `stupid = Me.SelectConsultantCombo`

Comment: The bound column is set to ContactInfoID, which is correct.  I tried the existing code with `Me.`, and also tried `stupid = Me.SelectConsultantCombo` and `stupid = Me.SelectConsultantCombo.Value` (tried both with and without `Me.`) and still got Error 94: Invalid use of Null pulling up that line in the debugger :\

Comment: You are setting it to Null here" `Me!SelectConsultantCombo = Null`. You should wait until you actually use it's value for your query before you reset it to null, so move that line to the SaveConsultantbtn_Click sub or save that value somewhere else. The way your code is, every time a selection is made the combo box is reset to null.

Answer (score 0):

I took `Me!SelectConsultantCombo = Null` out of the combo's afterupdate and it works perfectly now! Of course if I have the combo set to null somewhere in the code it's going to pull up null somewhere else, d'oh!